# Can EF Core map a GET (calculated) property?

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model class that has an array of objects which I want to store in the database. In order to fit this data into a single row and column; I have a `get` property which concatenates the array and returns a single string. I want to store this concatenated string in the database.

```
[NotMapped]
public object[] Values { get; set; }

public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join("|", this.Values);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that the Value property contains the string that I expect. However, this does not save to the database; it just saves it as NULL. I do not have any special mapping code in place; it is relying on the defaults of having the column name match the property name.

The closest thing I have found it [this tutorial](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/11/07/efcorefields/) which describes using the HasField() method to map the column to a private field instead of a property; but in my case it's not just that I have a private set; it's that I don't have any set property at all.

Comment: Why don't you just set the `string Value` field in the `set` method of `object[] Values` too?

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo I actually got that idea almost right after posting the question... since the object is being created by automatically parsing Json with Newtonsoft, I wasn't sure if it would have an issue with a property being more complex than a normal get/set; but it seems to work!. I am still curious about the question as-asked; because doing it this way seems like a workaround; and it wouldn't work if, for example, the get-only property were not simply calculated based on another property I already have.

Comment: @Gendolkari, can you explain what do you mean with the last thing you said? Do you mean if `Value` needs to be calculated using more than one single property?

Comment: As a trivial though maybe-not-useful example, what if Value returned DateTime.Now instead? Or, yes, such as if Value were based on multiple properties.

Comment: `No backing field could be found for property 'SomeValue' of entity type 'MyEntity' and the property does not have a setter`. Maybe this explains a little bit about EF Core. It seems like you need to specify a setter for a mapped property. So, in any case, the setter should set the value using the properties you want to use and retrieve that value with the `get` accessor

Comment: I suppose a more realistic but still simple example would be if you had FirstName and LastName regular properties, and also a FullName{get{return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";}} and you wanted to store FullName in the database.

Comment: Well, in that case you have two options:
**1:** Create a blank setter and leave the return logic in the get accessor, as @Claudio Valerio suggested (for simple scenarios)
**2:** Create a setter for that property to take the values from the properties you want and store the result in a private field, then, retrieve that private one from the get accessor. (for more complex scenarios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do somethig like this?

```
private object[] values;

[NotMapped]
public object[] Values { 
    get => values;
    set {
        if (value != values);
        values = value;
        Value = string.Join("|", value);
    }
}

public string Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: When I create a new instance would this work correctly? `var object = new MyObject { Values = new[] {"one", "two"}, Value = "Another values" }`

Answer (score 1):

You can trick EF by doing something like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public object[] Values { get; set; }

public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join("|", this.Values);
    }
    set {}
}
```

Setter won't do anything, so you achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this works, but it does! It feels a bit more hacky than the other solution though; very weird quirk in EF apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach not to mix business and persistence structures.

Other parts of application should care/know how data is stored.

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}

public class ValuesEntity
{
    public static ValuesEntity From(BusinessObject object)
    {
        return new ValuesEntity { Values = string.Join("|", object.Values) };
    }

    public string Values { set; set; }

    public BusinessObject ToBusinessObject()
    {
        return new BusinessObject { Values = Values.Split("|") };
    }
}
```

With this approach you will explicitly "tell" other developers or reader of the code your intentions.
Working with different classes for each responsibility(business logic or persistence) will be simpler because both responsibilities are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good use case for a [value convertor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives).

You keep the array property mapped and supply a value convertor for it when you configure the EF model. The value convertor will dump all values in a single string when saving to the DB, and will split a string into array of values when reading from the DB. You can program any logic in it.